# How should questions containing spammy and porny links be handled?

Tags: discussion

How should the below question be handle? Is it good to post it as is? Or should I only describe the links as spamy and pornny and cut them off? The advantage of the former is that people can have full details, and the advantages of the latter is that we don't advertise the links, the question is much shorter, and people don't have to feel embarrass for seeing them. If we choose the latter solution, then is there any situation the former is better?

For the sake of the discussion I will post it as is now.

> I click a link with good content (this doesn't guarantee the site isn't compromised) and the browser gives me this error:

[image]

> I wonder in what situation this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific links aren't relevant to your question. For brevity, list a couple and ellipsis the rest.

Comment: Should I hide the porn links or just treat them like normal links? Should I avoid saying the word "porn" at all, and use "spammy and similarly links" instead?

Comment: I'm saying that the links are completely irrelevant, so don't include any of them or focus on them. You appear to be concerned about the links, but the focus should be on the certificate. Include the certificate, not the links.

Comment: Is this fine? https://security.stackexchange.com/q/255588/94500

Comment: looks fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

If the spam addresses are important to the question, you can replace the addresses with images showing the addresses.  For example, your original question didn't need to list the exact addresses.  However, this question relies on seeing the *volume* of addresses as a part of the meta-question, so they're more relevant.

In many cases, addresses of spam sites are intentionally included in as many locations as possible as a part of link optimization.  Any time an address can be associated with a reputable, non-spam, non-porn address can add to its "legitimacy" when ranking the address for quality. Try to never include them directly.